# Images to Executables?

Tags: android, image, text, opengl-es, maya

I have an app that uses a lot of images for drawables. However, because they are in high definition quality they take a lot of space. Is there anyway in android that I might be able to convert these images into text or since I am using Maya save them in a different format so that my app can draw them?  In other words is there a way to create a code that draws the image via points given by text yet still has a good quality?

Comment: The only way is to compress them, but well yea, then you lose some quality.

Comment: Err, let me get this straight. You want to take a bitmap image and turn it into a vector graphic? This can be done, but is not always going to save you storage (especially if your images are actual photos).

Comment: It would help if you could show us what kinds of images your looking to compress. The general strategy of using lossy images is as good as it gets for most cases. However there are many exceptions, like the backgrounds of the game Homeworld. So sometimes the material makes it worth while to use different schemes.

Comment: [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) might do for simple images.

Comment: My images are PNG format.  Since they are used for a reference app I do need them to be the best quality possible. Unfortunately they are around 2-3 mb each and after compression 1-2 mb so don't save too much space. I was just wondering if there was a better way to store or use these images or if they could be rendered in app. I wouldn't mind using an apk expansion file but I didn't think that was possible with drawables.

Comment: You can export SVG from Maya using the vector render plugin